# FFMPEG 2.5.4 build for Android with NDK r10d

Tags: android, macos, ubuntu, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build FFmpeg for android following this tuto: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

I'm using:

- NDK r10d
- FFMPEG 2.5.4

I have tried to build on MacOs and Ubuntu and I get the same error when I execute ./build_android.sh:

```
`Creating config.mak, config.h, and doc/config.texi...
./build_android.sh: line 16: --prefix=/Users/jesusmartin92/Documents/android-ndk-r10d/sources/ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/arm: No such file or directory
./build_android.sh: line 18: --enable-shared: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 20: --disable-static: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 22: --disable-doc: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 24: --disable-ffmpeg: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 26: --disable-ffplay: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 28: --disable-ffprobe: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 30: --disable-ffserver: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 32: --disable-avdevice: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 34: --disable-doc: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 36: --disable-symver: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 38: --cross-prefix=/Users/jesusmartin92/Documents/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-: No such file or directory
./build_android.sh: line 40: --target-os=linux: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 42: --arch=arm: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 44: --enable-cross-compile: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 46: --sysroot=/Users/jesusmartin92/Documents/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/: No such file or directory
./build_android.sh: line 48: --extra-cflags=-Os -fpic -marm: command not found
./build_android.sh: line 50: --extra-ldflags=: command not found`
```

It's like the script doesn't find the ndk folder, but I checked and the path is OK. The script "build_android.sh" is in the ffmpeg folder. This is the content of it:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/Users/jesusmartin92/Documents/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

I'm very stuck, so any idea will be well received.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem. I put the configure command in one line and it worked!! I don't know why it was failing...

Anyway, Now I'm using this project (https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java) so, I don't have to compile anything. I think it's the easy way to use FFMPEG in our Android applications.

EDIT: I finished my project. You can check my work on GitHub:
https://github.com/JesusMartinAlonso/Video4Share

Comment: I had trouble with the project you are using. It's great having it as a dependency and not having to compile anything but it seems to be compiled with very few features like filters for example. I'd would be wise to check what is being enabled in the configure call and make sure something you need is not missing.

Comment: I got this error: make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all
./x264_build.sh: line 21: ./configure: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

put the bin file of the ndk in the same directory of your ndk.

Enter the command prompt

go to the directory using the command prompt.

Enter:  chmod a+x android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin
then: ./android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin

(assuming you have a 64 bit machine)

now you have the ndk.

go to the ndk folder then sources and extract ffmpeg-2.6 there

create a file called build_android.sh containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################
# Usage:
# put this script in top of FFmpeg source tree
# ./build_android
# It generates binary for following architectures:
# ARMv6 
# ARMv6+VFP 
# ARMv7+VFPv3-d16 (Tegra2) 
# ARMv7+Neon (Cortex-A8)
# Customizing:
# 1. Feel free to change ./configure parameters for more features
# 2. To adapt other ARM variants
# set $CPU and $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS 
# call build_one
######################################################
NDK=../..
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=arm \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-demuxer=mov \
    --enable-demuxer=h264 \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --enable-protocol=file \
    --enable-avformat \
    --enable-avcodec \
    --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
    --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
    --enable-decoder=h263 \
    --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-parser=h264 \
    --disable-network \
    --enable-zlib \
    --disable-avfilter \
    --disable-avdevice \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

make clean
make  -j4 install
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/libgcc.a
}

#arm v6
#CPU=armv6
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7vfpv3
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one

#arm v7vfp
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU "
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU-vfp
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7n
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -marm -march=$CPU -mtune=cortex-a8"
#PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--enable-neon
#build_one

#arm v6+vfp
#CPU=armv6
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-DCMP_HAVE_VFP -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=./android/${CPU}_vfp 
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one
```

enter command prompt and go to the ffmpeg-2.6 folder then enter:

sudo chmod 755 build_android.sh

./build_android.sh

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found other solution ;)

Comment: Would you like to explain "--extra-cflags" and "--extra-ldflags" values?

Comment: And where is output? What is output path?!